# Why do phosphorescent screens need electron energy in order of KeV to emit light, when visible light photons only need ~eV?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-dots

All phosphorescent screens operate at ~KeV energies, but emit photons with energies ~eV. Why is such a high input energy necessary?
What is the situation with quantum dots, do they also require hight energies for cathodoluminescence?
Would hitting a P-N junction of LED with ~eV electron beam cause it to emit light?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_phenomenon  "A phosphor is a substance that exhibits the phenomenon of luminescence; it emits light when exposed to some type of radiant energy. The term is used both for fluorescent or phosphorescent substances which glow on exposure to **ultraviolet or visible light**,".  Are you talking of cathode ray tube ?"cathodoluminescent substances which glow when struck by an electron beam (cathode rays) in a cathode ray tube. "

Comment: this video for cathodoluminescence https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U9_IejOaEqE

Comment: I don't know the answer, but it could be entirely practical: What if it, entirely apart from the question of how much energy is needed to excite the phosphor, it was not possible to build a cathode-ray tube that could form and focus an electron beam using only a few Volts?

Comment: @annav, You are right, I'm talking about cathodoluminescence, not a phosphorescence. Although, term "phosphor" is also used for cathodoluminescent materials, thus "phosphor screen".
Thanx for the video, I used to work with Sangeetha :)))